# Select all rows that have a hamming distance less than n?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hamming-distance

I have a database containing a column "hash" for each row that is a varchar string. is there a way in SQL to select all the rows that have a hamming distance of less than n from a string I provide.

for example if I provide the string `"abdfaqsv102asd"` I want to find all the rows where the hash column has a hamming distance of less than n from that string.

Comment: sample input and sample output

Comment: check this.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/fast-hamming-distance-queries-in-postgres